# Choosing IPS screen for laptop

Tags: laptop, displays

This question might seem weird at first, but I *do* mean it.

**I want to buy a good IPS screen for my laptop.**
This is not about price or compatibility, but about **quality**.
I want to buy *just screen, **not** the whole laptop*.

---

#### Long story short

In (most) modern laptops, screen is connected to motherboard using **Embedded DisplayPort connector**. **As I understand** (and according to my experience), there are **no vendor-specific variations**, just a few standard variants (namely 20, 30 and 40-pin connectors). It is just a plain DisplayPort interface with cheaper/smaller connector and added pins for backlight and power.

What it means is that as of today, laptop screen compatibility question boils down do "Does it (physically) fit (including connector)?", which is easily answered for example by looking at photo.

So basically, choosing laptop screen should be almost the same as choosing external monitor.
Except one thing.
I have seen nothing like *"AUO b156han01.2 IPS panel review"*. **Have you?**

---

#### Solution I want

I basically want a **general** suggestion on how to find LCD panel of specific size, with specific (e.g. 30-pin eDP) connector, that has desired qualities (e.g. brightness of at least 300 cd/m²) and does not have problems like obviously uneven backlight or wrong colors.

The obvious solution "search for laptop and then buy original panel" will not do, same way as searching for preassembled PC with everything included will not do if you only need a monitor.

---

#### Edit

A few days later, I suspect that my question is pointless.
There is no such market as "generic screens for laptops".
You often can by a laptop without HDD or RAM, but without display? I guess no.
So, chosing a laptop and only buying screen might be the only solution for now.

Let's hope I am wrong.

---

#### Edit2

Now question is closed. I kind of suspected that less general questions are expected :)

Nevertheless, I might have found something:
Lenovo Y50 has such a bad screen that very long forum threads appeared that are dedicated to replacing it, and these threads have quite a few useful links.

I currently do not have time to explore these links, but I got a general idea:
If you search for display panels in general (including LED matrices, text LCDs with serial interface, industrial displays, etc.), you *will* find some sites that offer laptop panels too and they will have quite some information on these panels.

Comment: I've never heard of anyone doing this, but this seems *potentially* awesome.

Comment: Geek, no one did it (at least) because eDP is common in 2012+ (?) laptops, and panels that use other semi-standard interfaces are likely incompatible.

Today, eDP connector on motherboard is likely wired directly to, say, Intel HD graphics inside CPU, so panels are likely to work the same in all laptops.

Also, **edit**ed question.

Comment: That is why its odd. Breaking out eDP is trivial too so in some cases buying a bare panel and a suitable controller would be awesome.

Comment: I've closed this question because it's more of a general advice-type question, which [are no longer in scope](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/343/do-we-still-want-general-advice-questions/345#345).

Comment: @Geek Not sure what you mean by "breaking out eDP", but the whole idea of eDP is that it can be used to drive LCD panel directly (much like LVDS that was used before, no complex logic on display side) and that it is completely standardized at the same time, allowing for direct connection between GPU and panel (unlike LVDS that required not so standardized converter chip on motherboard which caused panel incompatibilities). And whatever "controller" display panel has, it is (almost?) never detachable, or even baked into glass (e.g. in smartphone displays).